# Why the value of this string is still null although I have checked if it is null?

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
String invite = LogInUtil.getInvite(this);
        System.out.println(invite.equals(null));
        if ( invite != null){

            System.out.println(invite);
            System.out.println("=============================================="+(invite != null));
            Invitation.setInvite(Long.valueOf(invite));
        }
```

This is the method in LoginUtil:

```
public static String getInvite(Context mContext){
    // 获取搜索记录文件内容
    SharedPreferences sp = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 0);
    String history = sp.getString(PREFERENCE_NAME, "");
    String[] tmpHistory = history.split("==");
    if (tmpHistory.length==2){
        return tmpHistory[1];
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the result in logcat:

```
I/System.out: false
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: ==============================================true
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Maybe is a stupid question. I'm a fresher,and I need your help. TTThanks!

Comment: `invite.equals(null)` would throw a NullPointerException if `invite==null`

Comment: `System.out.println(invite == null);`

Comment: Given your output, I'd say the value of `invite` is the String `"null"`.

Comment: As already pointed out by @Eran, the value of `invite` is `null` String

Comment: I agree with @Eran, add a `System.out.println("null".equals(invite));` to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be case you are getting "null" as string value rather than null, try below code, if still not work try to clean your project

```
String invite = LogInUtil.getInvite(this);

            if ( invite != null && !"null".equals(invite)){

                System.out.println(invite);
                System.out.println("=============================================="+(invite != null));
                Invitation.setInvite(Long.valueOf(invite));
            }
```

Comment: Thank u very much.I put "null" into my sharedprefrence,that's why I get "null" rather than null in the method of  getInvite（）;

Answer (score 0):

The error is at this line `invite.equals(null)`. Your are checking `null.equals(null)` that's why it throws `NULLPointerException`.

Please correct it to the `System.out.println(invite == null);` so it will not throw exception.

> Corrected Sample code

```
String invite = LogInUtil.getInvite(this);
        System.out.println(invite == null);
        if ( invite != null){

            System.out.println(invite);
            System.out.println("=============================================="+(invite != null));
            Invitation.setInvite(Long.valueOf(invite));
        }
```

Comment: Where has @Motee mentioned that it is throwing `NULLPointerException`? It might if the value of `invite` is actually null which isn't the case

Comment: It would throw NullPointer exception. if invite is null

Comment: It would throw NPE if `invite` were `null`. But obviously it is not. Seems `invite` is `"null"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringUtils.empty() method for checking null and empty in case of string.

I think u are getting "null" string in ur invite variable.